# Gridview cells shows blank value in Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm creating website in Asp.net (Framework 4.0).

In this website I have taken a Gridview which is filled with data on page load.

**Now I'm trying to Insert data from Gridview to database on button click. While inserting into database GridView Cells shows blank values.**

Code as follows for GridView Binding

```
void BindGrid()
 {
   GridView1.DataSource = obj3.GetCart(sid, uid);
   GridView1.DataBind();
   int rowCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
   if (rowCount == 0)
    {
       GridView1.Visible = false;
       lblCartCount.Visible = true;
       lblCartCount.Text = " No Items In Cart";
    }
    else
    {
       GridView1.Visible = true;
       GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = "Total Price";
       GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[3].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
       GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[9].Text = totals.ToString();
       totprice = Convert.ToInt32(totals.ToString());
       totals = 0;
       lblCartCount.Visible = false;
   }
 }
```

Code for Insert button click for Insert data from Gridview to database.

```
 protected void btnOrderNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow g1 in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        BindGrid();
        val1 = obj4.AddOrderItem(orderid, Convert.ToInt32(g1.Cells[2].Text),
        Convert.ToInt32(g1.Cells[5].Text), Convert.ToInt32(g1.Cells[4].Text),
        Convert.ToInt32(g1.Cells[6].Text), Convert.ToInt32(g1.Cells[7].Text),
        g1.Cells[0].Text, Convert.ToInt32(g1.Cells[1].Text));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer by myself. The code for Insert data from Gridview to database has some following changes .

```
protected void btnOrderNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow g1 in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        string sss = (((Label)(g1.Cells[g1.RowIndex].FindControl("lblSession"))).Text.Trim());
        int uuu = int.Parse(((Label)(g1.Cells[g1.RowIndex].FindControl("Label5"))).Text.Trim());
        int itemid = int.Parse(((Label)(g1.Cells[g1.RowIndex].FindControl("lblItemId"))).Text.Trim());
        int priceid = int.Parse(((Label)(g1.Cells[g1.RowIndex].FindControl("lblPriceId"))).Text.Trim());
        int quantity = int.Parse(((Label)(g1.Cells[g1.RowIndex].FindControl("lblItemQuantity"))).Text.Trim());
        int price = int.Parse(((Label)(g1.Cells[g1.RowIndex].FindControl("lblPrice"))).Text.Trim());
        int bprice = int.Parse(((Label)(g1.Cells[g1.RowIndex].FindControl("lblBulkPrice"))).Text.Trim());

        val2 = obj4.OrderTempCartUpdate(sss, uuu);
    }

}
```

In this instead of taking only g1.Cells[0].text wasn't able to find particular row index . So  I have added 
(((Label)(g1.cells[g1.RowIndex].FindControl("LabelName"))).

instead of g1.Cells[0].text;